# How to get data from model class in Angular4

Tags: angular

I am working in an Angular4 project,In this I am storing the API response to model class ,Now I want to retrive the data from model class to component .

service - model - component - htmlpage

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Data } from '@angular/router';
import {Images} from '../images'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Injectable()
export class CartdataService {

  public i_product_Path = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  i_cast_Product_Path = this.i_product_Path.asObservable();
  current_product :any;
  private serviceUrl :string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 get_Product_Path(pName: string) : Observable<Images[]>{
    this.current_product = pName.trim();
    this.serviceUrl =`http://localhost:abc/api/data/GetImage/?imageName=${this.current_product}`;
    return this.http.get<Images[]>(this.serviceUrl);
  }
}
```

Here I call the API and store the value in model class.

Model class

```
export interface Images {
    big_Images: string[];
    small_Images: string[];
    selected_Product_Images: string[]
  }
```

Component

Here I want to call the model class and get all API response then display it to the html pages.but I don't know how to call the model class inside the component and get the values from model.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CartdataService } from './cartdata.service';
import { Images } from './model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService) {}
   ngOnInit() {}
}
```

API response structure:

[image]

Comment: Well, you call the service, subscribe to the returned observable, and store the emitted Images[] in a field of your component. What exactly is the problem? Have you read the Angular guides about HttpCLient and observables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define:

```
export class AppComponent  {
bigImages: Images[];
smallImages: Images[];
spImages: Images[];
  constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService) {}
   ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Then you should call in ngOnInit or in any other place, depending on your need, where `pName` is your variable you send to service:

```
this.CartdataService.get_Product_Path(pName)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.bigImages = data['0'];
            this.smallImages = data['1'];
            this.spImages = data['2'];
         },
         error => { // here you handle errors },
         () => {
               // here you do something else
                });
```

Comment: it shows the error as follows type Images is not assignable to type Image[]

Comment: this.bigImages = data['0']; I have added '' which I forgot first time

Comment: Joe Belladonna ,It's working for me ,Now I trying to print the values inside the span tag it shows like <span>hi--{{smallImages[0]}}</span>
[object object],Actually I want to print all the values in separate span tags

Comment: @Nikson you shouldn't use it like that. You need `*ngFor` for that. Do a `console.log(smallImages)` like`() => {  console.log(smallImages)  });` Then run your code to see what is the structure of your `smallimages`. Then paste it here so we can determine how to call it in your HTML.

Comment: When I refresh the browser window the values are gone ,How can I prevent it ...?

Comment: @Nikson You can't prevent lose of data if you do refresh. It is like you have restarted your desktop application. But, if you put your call  for data in `ngOnInit`, then your call will be executed every time you do refresh and you will get your data.

Answer (score 0):

You define and use Model as an interface. The interface in angular usually use check data type and structure.

So, you do not need to use the Model as a function.

in component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CartdataService } from './cartdata.service';
import { Images } from './model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService) {}
   ngOnInit() {}
   callService(){
    this.cartdataService.get_Product_Path('somePath').subscribe(
      result => {   // <= you define Observable<Images[]> data type in service.ts
        let imageResult: Images[] = result;

        //Do something here
        console.log("imageResult : ", imageResult);
      },
      error => {},
      () => {}
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it shows the error as follows type Images is not assignable to type Image[]

Comment: @Nikson I changed my codes which makes that error. but I guess you should check the interface and data response since it does not fit well.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm not really sure why you are writing the variables with _, isn't camel case enough? It brings a bit of complexity when reading your code.

Secondly, the response API isn't really your most desired one, instead of having an array of objects, you could have 3 fields that have string arrays as values, 1st object smallImages, 2nd object bigImages and the 3rd you selected Images; it would look something like this:

```
{
  smallImages: [
    "assets/Images/ProductDetailsPage/show1.png",
    "assets/Images/ProductDetailsPage/show2.png"
  ],
  bigImages: [
    'assets/Images/ProductDetailsPage/ProductDetailsPageThumbnails/bal1.png',
    'assets/Images/ProductDetailsPage/ProductDetailsPageThumbnails/bal1.png'
  ],
  selectedProductImage: ['assets/Images/ModalScreen/added.png']
}
```

This would ease a bit your implementation and it can be mapped directly on your model.

**You can see an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qoy2ug) with the working example, feel free to update it with your API response.**